# ValueError in while loop inside a function

Tags: python

The problem:

Write a function `add_up` that adds integers provided by the user, stopping when the user writes `Stop`.

Conditions:

- it has to be user input, so no parameters
- nothing is told about what to do with other strings that cannot be converted to integers

My answer:

```
def add_up():
    string = 0
    total = 0
    while string is not "Stop":
        string = int(input())    
        total += string    
        print(total)
add_up()
```

Comment: You have indentation errors. Please fix.

Comment: You didn't ask a question. Are we supposed to guess? In any event, `is` isn't the way to test for equality, and your string will *never* be equal to `"Stop"`.

Comment: so what is the question/problem here?

Comment: Well, if you ever entered a string "stop" then casting to int will fail. You need a `try`/`except`, look into exception handling. You also need `==` not `is not` to check for equality.

Comment: Exactly!! I am confused about how to structure it since only number strings can be converted to integers. Is there a way around the exception handling since this problem should be solved without this knowledge. Maybe a more basic way? In the course that I am taking I haven't learned about exception handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `try/except` to handle invalid inputs:

```
def add_up():
    string = 0
    total = 0
    while True:
        string = input()
        try:
            num = int(string)
            total += num
            print(total)
        except ValueError:
            if (string.lower() == "stop"):
                print("this ends now!")
                break
            else:
                print("not a number")
add_up()
```

also if you don't want to use `try/except` you can use `if/else` statements and `isidigit()` function:

```
def add_up():
    string = 0
    total = 0
    while True:
        string = input()
        if (string.lower() == "stop"):
            print("this ends now!")
            break
        elif (string.isdigit()):
            num = int(string)
            total += num
            print(total)
        else:
            print("not a number")

add_up()
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been puling my hair with this one. However I have not learned about try/except yet. Is there any other more basic way to solve this?